# Handling XML embedded in .NET assembly vs. external file: what's wrong with my code?

Tags: .net, xml, embedded-resource, xmldocument

Please tell me why these 2 don't give me the same XmlDocument object.

1. I can successfully load an **external** xml file using this code and successfully process the xml file:

   ```
   var xElem = XElement.Load("Products.xml");
   ```
2. Now I embed the xml file as **embedded resources** in the assembly instead:

   ```
   var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
   var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(this.GetType(), "AppNameSpace.Products.xml");
   var xElem= new XmlDocument();
   xElem.Load(stream);
   ```

Aren't the 2 xElem's supposed to be the same? Both XmlDocument containing the same info in Products.xml?

What did I do wrong? Thanks.

If I want to get the same xElem as in scenario 1, what must I do in scenario 2?

Comment: What is the difference between the two objects? They should load exactly the same structure, unless your files are different.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski The files are exactly the same. That's why I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Where in your project structure is that "Products.xml" and where is the code you showed? The `GetExecutingAssembly` gets the dll of the executing code - if the xml file is in a different assembly, it will not be found.

Comment: @HansKesting I believe I have only one assembly. I will check again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your XML file as a resource i.e. set "Build Action" to "Embeded Resource" in your Properties window when you add the file to the project.

See the following links

- [Adding and Editing Resources (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Code: Finding the Names of Resources in an Assembly (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287526%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Check if your image exists in the resources with this

```
thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string [] resources = thisExe.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

Edit: Ok I just checked, you need to set the "Build Action" to "Embeded Resource". Setting it to "Resource" will not work. Do this, and check for the name of the resource with the above code. I'm sure it will work.

Comment: This is what I did and the resource couldn't be found. Definitely my mistake but I haven't figured out where.

Comment: Check if you have some other namespace set in your project properties. Something that is different to what you are accessing.

Comment: Or check the names for all resources in your project. See my answer edit for code and links.

Answer (score 2):

"Products.xml" needs the applications namespace before it. Have you checked if the stream or the XML Data is null?

Comment: This is one of my errors. I am not sure it's the only one error in my code though. I am working on fixing this. Thanks.

Comment: I still have the problem after adding in the app namespace before the file name. stream is still null after GetManifestResourceStream().